# Angular animation not working for iOS 7

Tags: angular, ios7, angular-animations, web-animations

I'm having an issue in my Angular 5 app:

I have the trigger for an angular-animation placed in a ul tag, which is meant to change its height from 0 to *, and it does work well in all devices eccept for devices running iOS 7.

When testing those, and triggering the animation, I get:

> "Attempting to configure ‘style’ with descriptor ‘{“enumerable”:true,“configurable”:true}’ on object ‘[object HTMLUListElement]’ and got error, giving up: TypeError: Attempting to configurable attribute of unconfigurable property."

logged in the console, and an error at polyfills.bundle.js:10096:

> "TypeError: ‘undefined’ is not a function (evaluating ‘b.style._set(a.propertyName(c),d)’)".

This causes my app to crash. Does anyone have any clue at all?

Thanks,
Matteo

Comment: Are you using the web animations polyfill? https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js

Comment: I started seeing the exact same issue in my unit tests after adding that web-animations package to my polyfills.ts file. Commenting it out cause my tests to pass now. It's probably something similar.

However, my tests pass if I import it this way instead:
`import 'web-animations-js'; // Not the .min.js version.`
`// import 'web-animations-js/web-animations.min';`